# Can I use Devise for my multiple-store site with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We're planning to develop a site which hosts multiple e-commerce stores. All the virtual stores share a database. (Kinda like shopify.com) So customers may think that the sites are separate. Customer emails are unique only within one vendor but not globally.

Is Devise suitable for such a site? If so, how? If now, can you recommend other options?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: The unique constraint on the email is just the beginning of your problems. You will have to take this into account with *all* unique constraints. You can remove the unique constraint on email, and instead add it to `email, store_id`. Another option is to build a multi-tenancy app: https://github.com/influitive/apartment. That might be more complicated than necessary depending on the scale of the project.

Comment: @DamienRoche plus it does not handle the user problematics AFAIK. i used devise in a multy-tenancy app once and it was not too bad. or at least it was not much worse than what my overall experience with devise is.

Comment: @DamienRoche Thanks for the input. For multiple tenance strategy, I prefer shared database. So https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant may work better for me. I should probably roll my own authentication logic.